# Is there any special relationship between 'same-named' HTML and JS files in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Delving into Meteor and trying to get my head around the structure of things.

I wanted to know whether there was any special relationship ('behind the scenes') between two files that share the 'same name' — e.g. "single_page.html" and "single_page.js" — I see in a lot of tutorials that for every HTML file a corresponding JS file is usually created.

I suppose this has to do, in my mind, with the concepts of scope and modularity — do files 'named the same' in Meteor enjoy any special access to each other?

A newbie question, I know, but any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no special relationship between similarly named files but certain names do have special meaning. I could try to enumerate them all, but the best place to look is in the docs about [structuring your app](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp).